# Reduce objects with same value in one key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object:

```
let dates = [
{
    "surveyDate": "111111`",
    "selectable": true
},
{
    "surveyDate": "222222",
    "selectable": true
},
{
    "surveyDate": "111111",
    "selectable": false
},
{
    "surveyDate": "333333",
    "selectable": false
},
{
    "surveyDate": "222222",
    "selectable": true
}
]
```

I want to remove
    {
        "surveyDate": "111111",
        "selectable": false
    }

and the second 
    {
        "surveyDate": "222222",
        "selectable": true
    }

because there is another object in the array with surveyDate = 111111, which has the selectable value of true. There are two `{ "surveyDate": "222222", "selectable": true }` so I need to remove the second one.

Basically, this array will have unique surveyDates.

I hope this is clear enough!!

Comment: is the array sorted? what does not work with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` and rebuild the objects.

```js
let dates = [{ surveyDate: "111111", selectable: true }, { surveyDate: "222222", selectable: true }, { surveyDate: "111111", selectable: false }, { surveyDate: "333333", selectable: false }, { surveyDate: "222222", selectable: true }],
    result = Array.from(
        dates.reduce((m, { surveyDate, selectable }) =>
            m.set(surveyDate, m.get(surveyDate) || selectable), new Map),
        ([surveyDate, selectable]) => ({ surveyDate, selectable })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary to store the date and the selectable. I notice that you want to remove the date if it has a duplicate and you prefer to remove the duplicate when the selectable is equal false. And finally convert the dictionary to array.

```
function removeDuplicates(dates) {
  distinctDates = {};

  for ({ surveyDate, selectable } of dates) {
    // If surveyDate doesn't exist add it, else keep the selectable true if was ever true
    if (!distinctDates.hasOwnProperty(surveyDate)) 
      distinctDates[surveyDate] = selectable;
    else distinctDates[surveyDate] = distinctDates[surveyDate] || selectable;
  }

 // convert key/value to array and return
  return Object.entries(distinctDates).map(([surveyDate, selectable]) => ({
    surveyDate,
    selectable,
  }));
}
```

**I believe you have a type in your array. First surveyDate has a backtick at the end.**